# E posivel usar o cURL para pegar um determinado ID ou CLASSE de uma pagina

Tags: php, libcurl

estou estudando php e estava vendo a função cURL e queria sabe se nela e possivel pegar o conteudo somente de um determinado ID de uma outra pagina

exemplo:

```
<div id="teste2">
     n pegar esse aqui
    </div>
<div id="teste">
 Pegar somente o conteúdo que esta aqui dentro
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode tratar o retorno do cURL com a classe DOMDocument

Comment: Não é possível usar curl para obter somente determinada parte do códigoi HTML, o que você pode fazer usar curl para pegar todo conteúdo HTML e depois fazer parse nos dados que você deseja.

Comment: @anderson n entendi como seria isso?

Comment: qual linguagem você está usando shellscript?

Comment: @anderson, estou utilisando php

Comment: Então melhor você usar DOMDocument como @AndersonCarlosWoss 
 falou da uma olha aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não será muito difícil se utilizares algo mais apropriado ao que queres fazer.

Necessitas de uma libraria para te ajudar fazer a interpretação do DOM devolvido.

Podes utilizar do DiDom

https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM

```
use DiDom\Document;

$document = new Document('http://wp.test/teste.html', true);
$posts = $document->find('#teste2');
echo $posts[0]->text();
```